# htaccess doesnt work in virtual hosts but yes in default site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

Im having some issues with the virtual hosts apache files and htaccess.
I have apache, updated to 2.6 yesterday. I installed 2 virtual domains on it, and disabled the default domain. 
All works fine, sites loads fine, no problems there.

The first virtual domain has a htaccess with +50 rewrite conditions and all them work fine!
I tried to add some conditions to the 2nd domain, but the ones that rewrite directories dont work.

This is the condition:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?username=$1
```

And there, the "sites-available" apache config files for each domain (only the relevant things):

DOMAIN 1:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/domain1.com/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

DOMAIN2:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain2.com
ServerAlias www.domain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/domain2.com/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

As you can see, there is no diference between them other than the path to main folder.
I dont understand whats wrong with it. 
Why the first domain works perfect and the second one no.

***Some things:***

A: Any other condition on the domain2 htaccess file works just fine, like redirec simply html to php, or errorhandlers, or just simply redirects to test.

B: I pasted the same rewrite condition in my first domain htaccess file, and it works perfect!

It looks like the apache config file is not working correctly.

Is there anything I must check/change?

I will appreciate any help, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try its tested and working:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

I believe the issue is that you have `MultiViews` enabled, you can also resume your 2 rules into 1 like I have done above.

This should go into the `.htaccess` of your domain2.

As a side note, you do not need 2 directories directives, you can remove this one:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
```

And keep just:

```
<Directory "/var/www/domain2.com/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```